# Find a word from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some values into a table like below :-

1. Bank Of America
2. testBank Of America
3. State Bank Of India
4. ICICI Bank
5. Test @Bank*

I want a query to get all the values which contains Bank only. Proper word should match.

Result should be like :-

- Bank Of America
- State Bank Of India
- ICICI Bank

Comment: You can't do that without using [Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) and adding a FTS index that covers this field. At least not in a performant way. If you use `LIKE` the server will have to scan and filter all rows in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to add spaces to the beginning and end of the column and then look for `' Bank '`:

```
where ' ' + col + ' ' like '% Bank %'
```